# Picker Views in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm facing a problem with my app in picker view in `didSelectRow` function

In some situations the picker view could be nil so all the instruction inside`didSelectRow` will read **no value** and the app crashes.

I tried many times with different solutions to prevent this crash but it's not working:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {
        if (self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "medNumDay") as? NSInteger) != nil {

        let NumDay = self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "medNumDay") as? NSInteger
        let NumMed = self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "medNum") as? NSInteger
        Counter = (self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "takenCounter") as? NSInteger)!
        theTimeSet = (self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "nextTime")as? Date)!
        numberforday = (24 / NumDay!)
        thegetting.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
        TotalDose.text = String(NumDay! * NumMed!)
        RemainDose.text = String(Int(TotalDose.text!)! - Counter!)
        NextTimes.text = thegetting.string(from: theTimeSet!)
        }
        else{
                TotalDose.text = "No"
                RemainDose.text = "No"
                NextTimes.text = "No"            
        }
}
```

**Another try**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {
        if (MEDARRAY.count < 1) {
    let NumDay = self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "medNumDay") as? NSInteger
    let NumMed = self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "medNum") as? NSInteger
    Counter = (self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "takenCounter") as? NSInteger)!
    theTimeSet = (self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "nextTime")as? Date)!
    numberforday = (24 / NumDay!)
    thegetting.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    TotalDose.text = String(NumDay! * NumMed!)
    RemainDose.text = String(Int(TotalDose.text!)! - Counter!)
    NextTimes.text = thegetting.string(from: theTimeSet!)
    }
    else{
            TotalDose.text = "No"
            RemainDose.text = "No"
            NextTimes.text = "No"            
    }
}
```

The problem is its still trying to get value of below codes with this **error: Index out of range**

```
let NumDay = self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "medNumDay") as? NSInteger
let NumMed = self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "medNum") as? NSInteger
Counter = (self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "takenCounter") as? NSInteger)!
theTimeSet = (self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "nextTime")as? Date)!
```

Comment: Friendly advice: stop using Objective-C-like code when writing Swift. Do not use `.value(forKey:)`, use subscript - do not use NSInteger but Int - do not cast as Optional just to force unwrap later, use optional binding - avoid using NSArray/NSDictionary, use Swift Array/Dictionary, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the items you are looking to identify are optionals but you need them to have non-nil values to execute the function, place a guard statement at the head of the function which tests that each value is available:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    guard row < MEDARRAY.count,
          MEDARRAY.count < 1,
          let NumDay : NSInteger = self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "medNumDay") as NSInteger,
          let NumMed = self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "medNum") as NSInteger,
          let Counter = (self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "takenCounter") as NSInteger
          let theTimeSet = (self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "nextTime") as Date else { print("Could not obtain all required values") ; return }

     // ... function continues here...
```

Note that you can chain the guard statement with commas, and also that these constants are not optionals : if a non-nil value is available they will be initialised as non-optional, otherwise the guard exception will be triggered. (Note also correction to your array test and the row input.)

This way, if you are unable to initialise these constants to non-nil values, the function will simply exit which should prevent the app from crashing. Of course, this does not address why the values are nil, but at least keeps execution going.

Hope that helps.

Comment: what should i put after -> what type of value should be returned

Comment: @ammari - apologies, that confused the issue. The function is the standard UIPicker function and returns void, hence the guard clause is able to exit by simply calling return. I've corrected my answer to take out the arrow.

Comment: Put the test for the number of items in MEDARRAY first in the list, and also introduce a check that row is also 0 - if MEDARRAY has only one entry and you're looking for an index > 0 it will crash. If there is still an error could you let me know what is the console output?

Comment: i just insert one itme in the list and rest of the function did not run

Comment: If there is only one item in the list your test should be MEDARRAY.count < 2